# Add a Cancel REST API function to existing API

Tags: rest, swagger, api-design

I am working on an existing REST API that has the following APIS for getting the status of certain tasks:

```
GET /Status              <-- Returns json array of status of all running tasks
GET /Status/{TaskID}     <-- Returns json Status="blah" item of status of task with TaskID
```

I now need to create a CANCEL API which cancels a specific task.
What is the correct '**RestFul**' way to do this?

Is it?

```
POST /Status/{TaskID}/Cancel
```

Or?

```
PUT /Status/{TaskID}/Cancel
```

Or something different?

Comment: Is there a payload for cancellation?

Answer (score 2):

I would think

```
DELETE /Task/{TaskID}
```